# Need to modify same device UDID in developer account

Tags: ios

I have added UDID in upper case in Developer account.Now its not allowing me to change it or to add the same UDID in lower case by clicking +(add new).I want to  know whether that particular device can still be used by any chance or I need other UDID for sharing the build. Quick answers are appreciated.

Very thankful in advance.

Comment: Not possible..U cannot modify it once it is registered. U can modify or delete  only at the time of renewal.

Comment: Contact Apple Support Team for further assistance..!

Comment: As a UDID is a hex number, it should make no different whether it's upper case or lower case. Does it?

Comment: There's no case difference. So the problem reported is that you want to add a device... that's already on the list?

Comment: did you solve this problem? I tried to email the apple support but no answer

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, Not possible..U cannot modify it once it is registered. U can modify or delete only at the time of renewal of your developer account.
Contact Apple Support Team for further assistance..!

**Refer Below Link:**

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24340

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use device. You can't edit UDID of device You added once.
after account expire You can remove devices which You want to remove and add/edit devices.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the confirmation and quick response.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that. Even if you disable the upper case UDID and try to add the lower case one, it simply re-enables the uppercase UDID.

You will need to call apple support and have them remove it, then you need to add it again.

Comment: Yes exactly, it  re-enabling the same uppercase UDID, Thank you for your valuable answer, I will contact apple support.

Answer (score 1):

A UDID is a hex number. There's no difference between upper case and lower case. You do not need to add or modify the UDID.